# Ошибки при выполнении команды sudo apt update

Tags: ubuntu, update, sudo, apt

При выполнении команды в Ubuntu

```
sudo apt update
```

вылезают следующие ошибки:

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                        
Err:3 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable InRelease                                                                
  403  Forbidden [IP: 34.120.127.130 443]
Hit:4 http://repo.yandex.ru/yandex-browser/deb beta InRelease                                                                       
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fish-shell/release-3/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                          
Hit:6 https://packages.riot.im/debian default InRelease                                                                             
Hit:7 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic InRelease                                                         
Err:8 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable InRelease                                            
  403  Forbidden [IP: 34.120.127.130 443]
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser/ubuntu focal InRelease             
Hit:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease          
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:11 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy InRelease
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1 706 kB]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [627 kB]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [319 kB]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [14,8 kB]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [915 kB]
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [676 kB]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [1 379 kB]
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages [414 kB]
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [238 kB]
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [856 kB]
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted Translation-en [122 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                                     
E: Failed to fetch https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt/dists/stable/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 34.120.127.130 443]
E: The repository 'https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt/dists/stable/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 34.120.127.130 443]
E: The repository 'https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Не могу понять, в чем проблема и как ее исправить

Comment: Ну собственно тебя не пускает в `artifacts.elastic.co`. Закаменть или удали строки с этой репой.

Comment: я не понимаю, в какой файл надо  открыть для этого

Comment: Какой выхлоп у `grep -r elastic /etc/apt/*`?

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list:deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list:deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main
Binary file /etc/apt/trusted.gpg matches

Comment: `sudo sed -i 's|^deb|# deb|' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic*`

Comment: спасибо, все получилось

Comment: Оформил как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Адрес `artifacts.elastic.co` запрещает к нему подключаться, менеджер пакетов это видит и из-за одной ошибки перестаёт обновлять всё остальное.

**Решение №1**. Написать в поддержку этого сайта с описанием проблемы. Возможно они не знают, что их директория отдаёт 403-ю ошибку.

**Решение №2**. Убрать адреса, чтобы apt вообще перестал оттуда пытаться что-либо получить.

**Ручной вариант**: пройтись по файлам в `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` и удалить\закомментировать всё¸ что связано с сайтом.

**Автоматический вариант**: `sudo sed -i 's|^deb|# deb|' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic*`. Делает то же самое, но быстрее.

Comment: `Возможно они не знают, что их директория отдаёт 403-ю ошибку.` Все они знают. Это "Добро пожаловать в современную Россию". Через иностранный VPN все загружается.

Comment: вместе с россией и снг заблочено, спасибо знаете кому за это

Comment: Если чё, есть https://mirror.yandex.ru/mirrors/elastic/

Comment: Всем привет!
А если репа нужна шоб elasticsearch-oss установить ? sudo sed -i 's|^deb|# deb|' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic* - не спасет

Comment: Тебе через докер же надо, верно?